# Enable/Disable the Save button correctly

Tags: c#

Let's say we have a Win32 form with a Save toolbar button and some sontrols like a CheckBox are on the form, now we write a one line code for onchange event of checkbox to enable/disable the Save button. Let's say checkbox is selected at first, Save button disabled, now de-select the checkbox, Save button becomes enabled...now select the checkbox again Save button is still enabled...Same for a TextBox for example. Let's say its text is "Hi"...change it to "Hi Bye" , Save is enabled...change it BACK to "Hi" as it was, Save remains enabled... 
Is there a model we can use to prevent these wrong enabling/disabling of save button?

Comment: Can you re-word that with paragraphs and something easier to read please! :)

Comment: Most text editors just don't bother. Undoing changes to the last saved version is handled, but manually editing back to what it was previously just requires too many checks.

Comment: well I was mostly thinking about a "IsDirty" logic, that can keep track of state of each control as an object and also keep a backup of those objects, compare them, decide if it is dirty..then enable the save button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the last saved state, and compare the current state to it whenever it changes, to see if they're identical. If so, disable the button.

If these comparisons are expensive, you could make this more efficient, by calculating a hash value over all of the fields that need to be saved, and only doing the proper comparison if the hash of the last saved state matches the hash of the current state.

Comment: I was mostly thinking about a "IsDirty" logic, that can keep track of state of each control as an object and also keep a backup of those objects, compare them, decide if it is dirty..then enable the save button..

Answer (score 2):

You need to write some `IF - ELSE` code in the `CheckedChanged` event of the Checkbox. Check what is the current state by inspecting the `Checked` proeprty of the control (checkbox) ,If yes set the Enabled proeprty of the Button to true, else false.

```
private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox2.Checked)
        button1.Enabled = true;
    else
        button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Assuming `checkBox2` is the name of the Checkbox and `button1` is the name of the Save button.

You can use the same IF ELSE logic for other controls also.  To Set the Value of the Textbox, Use the Text  property

```
 TextBox1.Text="I am gonna try something now"l
```

**EDIT :** As [comecme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/537956/comecme) suggested, If you only want to enable/disable button based on the checbox, It can be done in one line instead of the IF else block like this

```
button1.Enabled=checkBox2.Checked
```

Comment: Simpler would be: `button1.Enabled = checkBox2.Checked;`

Comment: @comecme: Yea. But i used the IF ELSE to make the OP understand what is and HOW such kind of problems should be solved. I will add this the answer as well.

Comment: I was mostly thinking about a "IsDirty" logic, that can keep track of state of each control as an object and also keep a backup of those objects, compare them, decide if it is dirty..then enable the save button..

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to put all my control state checking and setting into a single method:

```
private void UpdateControls()
{
    saveButton.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked;
    otherButton.Visible = checkBox2.Checked && textBox.Text.Length > 0;
}

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateControls();
}

private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateControls();
}

private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateControls();
}
```

This means you just have one place in which to check and set the state, and makes it much easier to understand what is going on, especially when you have complex forms. I also prefer boolean expressions rather than if statements when assigning boolean variables, because it caters for both true and false without having to write a separate else statement (which may be forgotten).

Comment: I was mostly thinking about a "IsDirty" logic, that can keep track of state of each control as an object and also keep a backup of those objects, compare them, decide if it is dirty..then enable the save button..

Answer (score 0):

I don't get where you're going with your checkbox, but I would use a Boolean variable:

```
private Boolean _canSave = false;
private Boolean CanSave 
{
    get { return _canSave; }
    set
    {
        _canSave = value;
        MenuSave.Enabled = value;
    }
}

public void MenuSave_Click()
{
    Save();
}

private void Save()
{
    // do your thing

    CanSave = false;
}

public void TextBox_TextChanged()
{
    CanSave = true;
}
```

This won't account for disabling the saving menu when you revert the text back to its original. If you want that, you'll have to store the text in the `Save()` method in a private variable, and compare that to the current text on every `TextBox_TextChanged()` to determine whether a change compared to the original (i.e. since last save) has occurred.

Comment: yeah I was mostly thinking about a "IsDirty" logic, that can keep track of state of each control as an object and also keep a backup of those objects, compare them, decide if it is dirty..then enable the save button...